# I want to convert pandas data into date timeindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
names=['Ticker','Date','Time','open','high','low','close','Volume']
havellsdata = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nEW u\Desktop\havellsjuly2015.csv',names=names,index_col= ' 
Ticker'])
k=havellsdata['high']-havellsdata['open']
havellsdata.insert(6,'openhighcheck',k)
havellsdata
#havellsdata[15]

    Date    Time    open    high    low close   openhighcheck   Volume
Ticker                              
HAVELLS 20150703    09:16:00    287.90  287.90  285.00  285.90  0.00    2978
HAVELLS 20150703    09:17:00    286.00  286.95  284.70  286.95  0.95    2684
HAVELLS 20150703    09:18:00    287.00  287.55  285.90  287.15  0.55    3717
HAVELLS 20150703    09:19:00    287.40  287.40  286.75  286.75  0.00    1451
HAVELLS 20150703    09:20:00    287.00  287.15  286.25  286.60  0.15    2721
HAVELLS 20150703    09:21:00    286.40  286.45  285.70  285.95  0.05    6084
HAVELLS 20150703    09:22:00    286.25  286.30  286.00  286.25  0.05    3466
HAVELLS 20150703    09:23:00    285.90  286.95  285.90  286.50  1.05    3831
HAVELLS 20150703    09:24:00    287.25  287.80  286.95  287.80  0.55    5686
HAVELLS 20150703    09:25:00    288.00  288.10  287.60  288.00  0.10    2844
HAVELLS 20150703    09:26:00    287.95  288.10  287.50  288.00  0.15    3149
HAVELLS 20150703    09:27:00    288.10  288.10  287.15  287.40  0.00    2216
HAVELLS 20150703    09:28:00    287.35  288.00  287.15  287.15  0.65    2511
HAVELLS 20150703    09:29:00    287.25  287.25  286.65  286.80  0.00    2744
HAVELLS 20150703    09:30:00    287.10  287.10  286.75  287.00  0.00    1588
HAVELLS 20150703    09:31:00    286.85  287.00  286.65  286.95  0.15    652
HAVELLS 20150703    09:32:00    286.85  286.90  286.75  286.75  0.05    481
HAVELLS 20150703    09:33:00    286.75  286.90  286.75  286.85  0.15    664
HAVELLS 20150703    09:34:00    286.90  287.00  286.75  287.00  0.10    608
HAVELLS 20150703    09:35:00    287.20  287.20  287.00  287.00  0.00    467
HAVELLS 20150703    09:36:00    287.00  287.15  286.70  286.70  0.15    2505
HAVELLS 20150703    09:37:00    286.50  287.40  286.00  287.40  0.90    4426
HAVELLS 20150703    09:38:00    287.40  287.65  286.45  286.75  0.25    5032
HAVELLS 20150703    09:39:00    286.65  288.25  286.65  288.05  1.60    5384
HAVELLS 20150703    09:40:00    288.05  288.50  287.80  287.80  0.45    8018
HAVELLS 20150703    09:41:00    287.70  287.70  286.45  287.40  0.00    9697
HAVELLS 20150703    09:42:00    287.55  287.55  287.05  287.10  0.00    1113
HAVELLS 20150703    09:43:00    287.30  287.45  287.00  287.45  0.15    2392
HAVELLS 20150703    09:44:00    287.65  287.65  287.05  287.10  0.00    857
HAVELLS 20150703    09:45:00    287.35  287.35  286.75  287.15  0.00    3159
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
HAVELLS 20150720    15:01:00    310.40  310.65  310.35  310.55  0.25    2222
HAVELLS 20150720    15:02:00    310.50  310.70  310.50  310.70  0.20    1250
HAVELLS 20150720    15:03:00    310.70  310.70  310.45  310.60  0.00    1667
HAVELLS 20150720    15:04:00    310.60  310.70  310.45  310.50  0.10    4395
HAVELLS 20150720    15:05:00    310.70  310.70  310.40  310.65  0.00    2580
HAVELLS 20150720    15:06:00    310.65  310.65  310.15  310.30  0.00    3864
HAVELLS 20150720    15:07:00    310.25  310.55  310.25  310.50  0.30    2275
HAVELLS 20150720    15:08:00    310.50  310.50  309.85  309.95  0.00    15803
HAVELLS 20150720    15:09:00    309.95  310.00  309.50  309.90  0.05    8086
HAVELLS 20150720    15:10:00    309.85  309.90  309.55  309.65  0.05    3743
HAVELLS 20150720    15:11:00    309.65  309.70  309.50  309.50  0.05    7241
HAVELLS 20150720    15:12:00    309.55  309.70  309.30  309.35  0.15    3823
HAVELLS 20150720    15:13:00    309.35  309.50  309.25  309.50  0.15    6280
HAVELLS 20150720    15:14:00    309.60  309.70  309.25  309.50  0.10    9540
HAVELLS 20150720    15:15:00    309.50  309.65  309.25  309.50  0.15    5264
HAVELLS 20150720    15:16:00    309.50  309.65  309.25  309.60  0.15    5783
HAVELLS 20150720    15:17:00    309.40  310.00  309.25  309.80  0.60    6529
HAVELLS 20150720    15:18:00    309.85  310.45  309.75  310.30  0.60    15943
HAVELLS 20150720    15:19:00    310.35  310.80  310.10  310.80  0.45    3616
HAVELLS 20150720    15:20:00    310.75  310.85  310.40  310.50  0.10    6405
HAVELLS 20150720    15:21:00    310.35  310.75  310.15  310.40  0.40    7800
HAVELLS 20150720    15:22:00    310.35  310.65  310.10  310.40  0.30    10439
HAVELLS 20150720    15:23:00    310.50  310.65  310.05  310.40  0.15    4467
HAVELLS 20150720    15:24:00    310.40  310.65  310.35  310.65  0.25    7938
HAVELLS 20150720    15:25:00    310.65  310.65  310.50  310.65  0.00    3290
HAVELLS 20150720    15:26:00    310.65  310.65  310.50  310.60  0.00    4851
HAVELLS 20150720    15:27:00    310.60  310.80  310.55  310.55  0.20    3662
HAVELLS 20150720    15:28:00    310.60  310.85  310.55  310.60  0.25    3874
HAVELLS 20150720    15:29:00    310.60  310.90  310.60  310.90  0.30    13271
HAVELLS 20150720    15:30:00    310.90  311.00  310.00  311.00  0.10    8751
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Your question seems all code, and not well formatted. Could you please take some of your time to properly format all the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
havellsdata['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(havellsdata['Date'].apply(str) + ' ' + havellsdata['Time'])
havellsdata = havellsdata.set_index('Datetime')
```

Example:

```
In [1723]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1723]: 
       Date      Time
0  20150703  09:16:00
1  20150703  09:17:00
2  20150703  09:18:00

In [1725]: df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(str) + ' ' + df['Time'])

In [1727]: df = df.set_index('Datetime')                                                                                                                                                                    

In [1728]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1728]: 
                         Date      Time
Datetime                               
2015-07-03 09:16:00  20150703  09:16:00
2015-07-03 09:17:00  20150703  09:17:00
2015-07-03 09:18:00  20150703  09:18:00
```

Comment: It gives this error  TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

Comment: @KeshavChoudhary Fixed. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thankyou this worked, i can now resample it in 15mins?